# Getting into differential equations

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm just getting into differential equations now and I've got to show that the given $y(x)$ is a solution to the differential equation: $$u'+u = 0 \ , \ y(x) = Ce^{-x}$$

How do I tackle this? I know nothing about differential equations and my book has the strangest explanations.

Comment: What's the derivative of $Ce^{-x}$?

Comment: It's $-Ce^{-x}$ but that doesn't ring any bells with me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The point is that you plug $y(x) = Ce^{-x}$ into the differential equation at the place of $u$ , and of course the derivative of $y(x)$ at the place of $u'$ (do you know how to differentiate $y(x)$?). Then you must show that the equality in the differential equation holds, that is $y'(x) + y(x) = 0$. So
\begin{align}
y'(x) + y(x) = -Ce^{-x} + Ce^{-x} = (-C+C)e^{-x} = 0\cdot e^{-x} = 0.
\end{align}
So it is, in fact, a solution since it equals zero as it should.

Answer (score 1):

You know that the derivative of $y(x)\exp x$ is a constant, so just compute it:

$$
0=\frac{d}{dx}\left[ \exp (x) y(x)\right] = \exp (x) y(x) +  \exp (x) y'(x) 
$$
and as the $\exp$ is never $=0$, $y(x)+  y'(x) =0$.

It also works the other way: if you consider a solution of the equation, then
$$\frac{d}{dx}\left[ \exp (x) y(x)\right]=0$$ and then it has the given form.

Answer (score 1):

We write
$$u^{'}=\dfrac{du}{dx}\\
\implies \dfrac{du}{dx}+u=0\\
\implies \dfrac{du}{dx}=-u\\
\implies \int\dfrac{du}{u}=-\int dx\\
\implies \ln|u|=-x+c\\
\implies \boxed{u=Ce^{-x}}$$
Let us now substitute:
$$\dfrac{du}{dx}+u=0\\
\implies \dfrac{d(Ce^{-x})}{dx}+Ce^{-x}=0\\
\implies \dfrac{d(e^{-x})}{dx}+e^{-x}=0\\
\implies -e^{-x}+e^{-x}=0\\
\implies 0=0$$
Q.E.D.

Comment: This is correct, but not what OP was asked to show. OP was merely supposed to plug $u$ into the differential equation and show it was satisfied. They weren't asked to derive the solution from first principles.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Ok. I will edit my answer.

Comment: @CameronWilliams See my edited answer.

Comment: Looks fine now. Just wanted to make sure your answer was relevant for OP. Thanks for being receptive to my comment!

Answer (score 0):

$$c\exp(-x)' + c\exp(-x) = -c\exp{-x}+c\exp{-x}=0$$

Answer (score -1):

This is a first order differential equation so called because the highest derivative is the first derivative (that is u'). To solve in this instance you simply separate the variables.  Let dy/dx = u' and y = u ;  dy/dx  + y = 0 ====> dy/dx = -y. From here you see that multiplying both sides by dx/y yields dy/y = - dx. Apply the integral operator and you get ln|y| = -x + ln C. Taking the antilogarithm of both sides and remembering you're rules of logarithms gives you the answer. Y = Ce^(-x) the general solution

Comment: Others don't show the process of how to actually get to the answer. Simply working backwards from the answer gives no understanding